# Array of object into a nested object for every value in the array

Tags: javascript, node.js

Trying to turn an array of objects into a nested object. Is there a good method for this? and how do I make it depending on the array length?

Working but is not universal:
https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-roentgen-3mdcjv?file=/src/App.js

What I have:

```
sorting: [
    {
    "id": "HighestDegree",
    "options": [
            "HighSchool",
            "Undergraduate",
            "Bachelor",
            "Master",
            "Doctor"
        ]
    },
    {
    "id": "gender",
    "options": [
            "male",
            "female"
        ]
    }
]
```

What I want:

```
value: {
    "Region": "Oklahoma",
    "HighestDegree": {
        "HighSchool": {
            "male": null,
            "female":null
        },
        "Undergraduate":{
            "male": null,
            "female":null
        }
    //and so on...
    }
}
```

The code beneath works but is hardcoded for only two different options. I want it to be able to nest the length of the array. So lets say another object was age it would be {"HighSchool":{male:{"<25":null,"25-35":null}}} etc..

```
function testSortingArray() {
    let sorting = [
      {
        id: "HighestDegree",
        options: ["HighSchool", "Undergraduate", "Bachelor", "Master", "Doctor"]
      },
      {
        id: "gender",
        options: ["male", "female"]
      }
    ];
    let GoalArray = {};
    if (sorting.length > 0) {
      sorting[0].options.map((firstArray) => {
        let currObject = {};
        sorting[1].options.map((secondOption) => {
          currObject[secondOption] = null;
        });
        GoalArray[firstArray] = currObject;
      });
    }
    return GoalArray;
  }
  console.log(testSortingArray());
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it with a recursive function.

The function below [reduces](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) every `options` array to an object, and then continues populating that object if there are `rest` elements left from the original `sorting` array.

```
const fn = ([{ options }, ...rest]) => options.reduce((a, v) => ({
  ...a,
  [v]: rest.length ? fn(rest): null
}), {});
const result = fn(sorting);
```

Besides the `reduce()` method, the code above makes use of object and array [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) and [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

---

**Complete snippet:**

```js
const sorting = [{
  "id": "HighestDegree",
  "options": [
    "HighSchool",
    "Undergraduate",
    "Bachelor",
    "Master",
    "Doctor"
  ]
}, {
  "id": "gender",
  "options": [
    "male",
    "female"
  ]
}, {
  "id": "age",
  "options": [
    "<25",
    "25-35"
  ]
}];

const fn = ([{ options }, ...rest]) => options.reduce((a, v) => ({
  ...a,
  [v]: rest.length ? fn(rest): null
}), {});
const result = fn(sorting);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Some explanation of the code would not be remiss as always.

Comment: Well, we get hundreds of questions a day about what syntax like `[{ options }, ...rest]` means, even before the currying.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Fair enough. Added some links for the more salient parts.

Comment: Beautiful and clean solution, great destructuring and usage of rest params length as a base case for recursion.